# Can cashew milk go bad, and how do you tell?

Tags: food-safety

How can you tell if your cashew milk has gone bad? If it is past the freshness code on package?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can go bad.

The date on the package is one indication, but it may be a "best by"  date and does not guarantee the milk will go bad by then. It doesn't necessarily mean it is guaranteed safe, either, although most stores will give you a refund on product that spoils early.

Look for the following signs (written for almond milk, but cashew milk follows the same rules):

> - the container seems abnormally bloated after opening
> - mold is present
> - any funky or pungent odors
> - the product has curdled or is visibly thick and slimy (observe the consistency when putting)
> - a change in color, as almond milk may appear more yellow when it has spoiled

[Source](http://www.theflamingvegan.com/view-post/How-to-Tell-if-Your-Non-Dairy-Milk-is-Spoiled-1)

Answer (score -3):

Smell it and you’ll know if it’s bad. They say regardless of expiration date, it’s good for one week after opening but I’ve had some 3 weeks   after opening and it’s still good so I guess just smell it to see